# \vrule inside smallmatrix

Tags: matrices, rules

I'm using `\vrule` in the `matrix` and `pmatrix` environments, and it works well. However, inside `smallmatrix`, `\vrule` doesn't fill all height of row. It looks that `smallmatrix` adds some vertical space after each row. Is it possible to get rid of it?

Here is minimal working example to compare `\vrule` in `matrix` (works well) and `small matrix` (doesn't work well):

```
\documentclass[12pt,sumlimits,a4paper,intlimits,namelimits,twoside]{article}
\overfullrule5pt
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} \usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} \usepackage[russian,ukrainian]{babel} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}   
$$   \begin{smallmatrix}   
2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\\[2pt]\hline    & \vline \\\\[1pt]  
2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline    
      \end{smallmatrix}\quad 
\begin{matrix}   2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\\[2pt]\hline    
   & \vline \\\\[1pt]  2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline \\\  2 & \vline     
\end{matrix} $$

\end{document}
```

The result of this example is below. 
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You should add a MWE!

Comment: @Black Mild  Thanks for reply. What is it MWE?

Comment: MWE= minimal working example. This is a rule of this site. Please read before asking for help!

Comment: @Black Mild MWE is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With new package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,sumlimits,a4paper,intlimits,namelimits,twoside]{article}
\overfullrule5pt
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} \usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} \usepackage[russian,ukrainian]{babel} \usepackage{array} \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}   
\[   
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={c|c},
    stretch=0,
    colsep=1.5pt,
    rowsep=1.5pt,
    row{4}={belowsep=2pt},
    row{5}={abovesep=2pt},
    column{1-2}={font=\scriptstyle},
    column{2}={colsep=2.7pt},
    }
2 & \\
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\hline
2 \\
2 \\  
2 \\
2
\end{tblr}
\quad 
\begin{tblr}{colspec={c|c}, column{2}={colsep=2.7pt}}
2 & \\
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\hline
2 \\
2 \\  
2 \\
2
\end{tblr}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`, you have the key `small`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{c|c}[small,cell-space-limits=1pt]
2 & \\
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\hline 
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\end{NiceArray}$
\qquad
$\begin{NiceArray}{c|c}
2 & \\
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\hline 
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
2 \\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]